# Loading data from a dynamically generated html url

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, dynamically-generated

I wanted to know is Selenium the only library that would be able to access data from a table in a webpage specifically [here](https://sslmate.com/labs/ocsp_watch/).

When I try to parse these sites using `bs4` it doesn't have any data in the tables just the headers, it works locally using `selenium`, but the issue is I don't have chrome or any browser for that matter on the box I'm working on. Wondering if there was another way.

Comment: You can use PyQt's webkit, which can operate as selenium in loading dynamic content that's generated by JavaScript: https://pawelmhm.github.io/python/pyqt/qt/webkit/2015/09/08/browser.html . Note that you may need to install a virtual buffer for rendering, such as [xvfb](http://www.xfree86.org/4.0.1/Xvfb.1.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you linked to loads another resource using AJAX (you can see this in the Network tab of the Inspector feature of your browser):

https://httpd.sslmate.com/ocspwatch/problems

It's plain JSON, you don't even have to scrape it:

```py
import requests

certificates = requests.get("https://httpd.sslmate.com/ocspwatch/problems").json()
for cert in certificates:
    print(cert["problem_time"], ":", cert["problem"], "(", cert["operator_name"], ")")
```

Output:

```
2023-03-10T00:11:32+00:00 : error parsing OCSP response: ocsp: error from server: unauthorized ( GoDaddy )
2023-03-10T00:14:58+00:00 : error parsing OCSP response: OCSP response contains bad number of responses ( eMudhra Technologies Limited )
2023-03-10T00:14:57+00:00 : OCSP responder does not know this certificate ( Netlock )
...
```

Comment: thank you! I should have inspected better!!